# Serial Console Forwarding over wifi

Tags: usb, serial

I am using a TTL to USB cable with my Raspberry Pi and I would like to forward that UART signal over the internet, or just over my own network via a usb to wifi chip of some sort. How would I go about doing this? What port would it be over? How would I access it via Macbook?

Yes, I am aware of ssh this is for debugging when my Pi does not boot far enough to turn on wifi.

**Originally posted on Hardware Recommendations**

Comment: I.e., you need to do TTL to IP...

Comment: @goldilocks Yes, I think that is more clear

Comment: The TTL end is plugged into the Pi.  The USB end is plugged into a computer.  Why not just walk to the computer or ssh into the computer?

Comment: You could do it with a 2nd RPi, but that's probably not what you want. I use `ser2net` for remote serial console access to Cisco equipment, using my RPi as a serial terminal server. You could connect a USB-TTY adapter the same way. Any other device will probably cost more than the RPi.

Comment: @joan the point is for debugging when the pi is unable to boot far enough to start ssh and I am not at home.

Comment: So you want to connect a couple of wires to the Pi's RX/TX/Ground and connect the other end to a dongle which talks wirelessly over a LAN?  That dongle is called a smartphone or a laptop and is not cheap.

Comment: This sounds like a job for [ESP-LINK: Wifi-Serial Bridge w/REST&MQTT](https://github.com/jeelabs/esp-link) (or similar helpers). I have played with ESP-8266ers but not yet with this firmware, so let someone who has tried this make an answer about this.

Answer (score 2):

There are some hardware modules available that provide access to a UART (TTL, RS-232, etc.) via a wired or wireless (802.11) TCP/IP connection. For example:

- http://en.usr.cn/low-price-low-power-ttl-to-wifi-802.11b-g-n-module.html
- http://en.usr.cn/Wifi-Serial-Server/rs232-to-Wifi.html
- https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11049

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a second RPi, like @bobstro suggested in the comment. This second RPi should be able to accept network connections, e.g. SSH, and provide access to the UART of the target RPi you want to debug.

Another (cheaper) alternative is to look into projects aiming at flashing Arduinos over the air. Many of these implement a UART-to-Wifi gateway on very cheap hardware like ESP8266. [Example](https://github.com/jeelabs/esp-link).